# Difference between expectations of the same random variable wrt different probability measures

Tags: probability, information-theory

$X$ is a measurable mapping from a discrete sample space $\Omega$ to $\mathbb R$.

$\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are two probability measures on $\Omega$. Assume they have probability mass functions $f_1$ and $f_2$.

Is $E_{\mu_1} X - E_{\mu_2} X \leq E_{\mu_1} \log (\frac{f_1}{f_2})$ i.e. $KL(\mu_1|\mu_2)$? I am not sure about it, since I can always scale $X$ arbitrarily.

I hope to relate the LHS to KL divergence in some way: 
$E_{\mu_1} X - E_{\mu_2} X \leq h(KL(\mu_1|\mu_2))$, for some function $h$.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If $\mu_1=\mu_2$ then both sides equal $0$. **This is the only situation in which the inequality is guaranteed to hold.**

To see this, pick an $\omega\in\Omega$ for which $\mu_1(\omega) \ne \mu_2(\omega)$, let $x\in \mathbb{R}$, and define

$$X(\omega) = x$$

and $X(\omega)= 0$ otherwise.  $X$ is measurable because the space is discrete.  Compute

$$\mathbb{E}_{\mu_1}(X) = \mu_1(\{\omega\})x = f_1(\omega)x;\quad \mathbb{E}_{\mu_2}(X) = \mu_2(\{\omega\})x = f_2(\omega)x,$$

whence

$$\mathbb{E}_{\mu_1}(X) - \mathbb{E}_{\mu_2}(X) = \left(f_1(\omega) - f_2(\omega)\right)x.$$

Since the difference in parentheses is nonzero, the right hand side can be made equal to any real number $y$ by choosing

$$x = \frac{y}{f_1(\omega) - f_2(\omega)}.$$

Comment: I see the proof for "if-part" but not the "only-if" part.

Comment: @user1669710 I don't follow: I haven't made any statement of equivalence. The assertion is that when the measures differ, then the inequality cannot hold for all random variables $X$.

Comment: Thanks; Also, I totally missed the "discrete sample space" part. I may still be incorrect, but I was wondering, in the continuous case if we define two different probability measures such that the expectations are equal, where as the KL-divergence is not. In which case, it looks like the inequality may hold even when the measures are not the same.

Comment: @user1669710 The same argument applies to *any* measures: if they differ, then random variables that assign huge values to elements of sets where the measures differ (and otherwise equal zero) can have arbitrary differences in their expectations.  *There simply is no useful connection between expectations, which depend on random variables, and the KL-divergence, which does not refer to random variables at all.*

Comment: Thanks whuber! Do you know if there is a $h$ so that $E_{\mu_1} X - E_{\mu_2} X \leq h(X, KL(\mu_1|\mu_2))$?

Comment: Because the left hand side can be *any real number,* what do you think?